# How to calculate the total of a column in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my table below, I've got the measure "Valor Total" as:

```
Valor total = SUM('Códigos e valores'[Valor unitário])*SUM(Csv[Quant.])
```

[image]

This works ok for all the rows of the table except for the grand total at the bottom, because the definition can't be quantity * price.

The problem here is that the field "Quant" is on a table with many-to-one relationship with another table (Table2).

This Table2 has a relationship of one-to-many to table "Códigos e valores" where field "Valor Unitário" is located.

Therefore, SUMX doesn't work in this scenario, not even with a RELATED in the expression.

But how to express this in the correct way?

Comment: Can you show your table relationship diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your two tables are related by some kind of `ID` column, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Valor total = SUMX(
                  SUMMARIZE('Códigos e valores',
                      'Códigos e valores'[ID],
                      "Quantity", SUM(Csv[Quant.]),
                      "Value", SUM('Códigos e valores'[Valor unitário])),
                  [Quantity] * [Value])
```

---

Maybe a better way to do this would be to create a measure using the `Csv` table instead:

```
TotalValue = SUMX(Csv, Csv[Quant.] * RELATED('Códigos e valores'[Valor unitário]))
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking in terms of the `Csv` table. Using that might be better. See my edit.

Comment: That one doesn't work, because Csv table is related (many-to-one) with Table2, which is related (one-to-many) to Códigos e Valores. So RELATED only works on the many side of a relationship. But thanks anyway!